# 404 not found when i try to delete some of my post

Tags: laravel, routes, destroy

I try to delete some of my post with slug but it's not found.
My route:

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/berita', DashboardController::class)->parameters([
    'berita' => 'post:slug'
])->middleware('auth');
```

My Controller:

```
public function destroy(Post $post) {
    $post->delete();
    
    return redirect('/dashboard/berita')->with('success', 'Berita sudah dihapus!');
}
```

My blade:

```
<form action="{/dashboard/berita/{{ $post->slug }}}" method="post" class="d-inline">
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
    <button class="badge bg-danger border-0"> </button>
</form>
```

Comment: sure because it can't find a route/URL/path for `{/dashboard/berita/...}` ... why do you have the `{ }` around your path?

Comment: Maybe try using the named route, like ` <form action="{{ route('post.destroy', $post )}}" >` ?

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot about that. But one more thing, this delete the post on my website but not deleted on my database, any idea?

Comment: Are you using soft deletes?

Comment: I posted as an answer if you want to accept

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is wrong, it should be
`action="/dashboard/berita/{{ $post->slug }}"`
Or better still, use a named route.

```html
<form action="{{ route('post.destroy', $post )}}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this section of your code: `action="{/dashboard/berita/{{ $post->slug }}}"`

you need to change it as below:

```
<form action="{{ url('/dashboard/berita/' . $post->slug) }}" method="post" class="d-inline">

</form>
```